# Bash profile messed up?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, terminal, bash

When trying to install Ruby on Rails using railsinstaller.org they messed up my system a bit after I uninstalled it and now my terminal prints this every time I start a new terminal up:

```
Last login: Fri Mar  1 15:01:45 on console
-bash: /etc/profile.d/sm.sh: No such file or directory
-bash: /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh: No such file or directory
```

I checked my `.bash_profile` and it doesn't reference anything like that. Any ideas of what's up and how to fix it?

I'm running Mac OS X by the way...

Comment: have you looked in you `.bashrc` file?

Comment: There's nothing in the `.bashrc` file

Comment: Look at other places like `~/.profile` `/etc/profile` `/etc/profile.d/*`

Comment: @Tuxdude, it was in `/etc/profile` Thanks! You can answer the question officially and I will reward your efforts :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually the shell sources a lot of files during startup and these are common locations that come to my mind:

```
~/.bashrc
~/.profile
/etc/profile
/etc/profile.d/*
```